# How do I load and use a static JSON file using CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I have gotten some advice to use "requirejs" but am having trouble making it work. I am a total newbie to CoffeeScript and new to JavaScript as well.

My JSON file (or more accurately a js file containing a JSON string) looks like this:

```
define(function(require)
{
  return 
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 30
  }
});
```

My app.coffee has:

```
requirejs.config
  paths:
    text: "<path to requirejs-text>"
    json_path: "<path to json file>"
```

My main.coffee has:

```
define(require) ->
  ko = require 'knockout'
  $ = require 'jquery'
  jsonObj = require 'json_path'

  class Main_App
    constructor ->
      @age = ko.observable jsonObj.age
```

I am getting the following error in my generated JavaScript:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

It is complaining about the colon in the line:

> "name": "Joe",

It seems clear that the javascript wrapper around my JSON string is not structured properly. I wanted to read a "data.json" file directly, but it was looking for a ".js" file. I was told I needed to wrap the JSON string in a javascript "define(function(require)", but I can't seem to find help on how to format it. Anyone able to get me unstuck?
Thanks!

Comment: According to JSON Lint, the embedded JSON string is valid. The problem seems to be the "javascript function wrapper" that needs to work with requirejs. I was instructed to make it look that way, such that it "returns" a JSON string.

Comment: Is there a better way to get CoffeeScript to read a "raw JSON" file that is not wrapped in javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Automatic Semicolon Insertion of JavaScript seems to be guilty here.

When you write

```
define(function(require)
{
  return // a ; is added here. 
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 30
  }
});
```

A semicolon is added behind your back after the return statement, so the function returns undefined instead of your object.

Try like this instead :

```
define(function(require)
{
  return {
    "name": "Joe",
    "age": 30
  };
});
```

Comment: Oi! Thanks much. I thought JavaScript was a whitespace agnostic language. I didn't realize it treats line breaks as implicit semicolons.